# Xpath to search for a node that has ANY attribute containing a specific string?

Tags: xml, xslt, search, xpath

I can search for a String contained in an *specific* attribute if I use the following XPath
`/xs:schema/node()/descendant::node()[starts-with(@my-specific-attribute-name-here, 'my-search-string')]`

However, I'd like to search for ANY attribute containing* a String

Comment: You need to be clear what you mean by "containing". Do you mean "equal to", or "having a substring equal to"? Or, as your example suggests, "starting with"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sample XML:

```
<root>
  <element1 a="hello" b="world"/>
  <element2 c="world" d="hello"/>
  <element3 e="world" f="world"/>
</root>
```

Suppose, we need to select elements which have any attribute containing `h`. In this sample: `element1`, `element2`. We can use this XPath:

```
//*[@*[starts-with(., 'h')]]
```

In your sample:

```
/xs:schema/node()/descendant::node()
    [@*[starts-with(@my-specific-attribute-name-here, 'my-search-string')]]
```

Comment: Is `//*[@*[starts-with(., 'h')]]` the same as `//*[starts-with(@*, 'h')]`?

Comment: @Eric, Nope. In 2nd XPath node-set passes to `starts-with` function as 1st argument (`@*`). The `starts-with` function converts a node-set to a string by returning the string value of the first node in the node-set, i.e. only 1st attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't this use the `contains` function?

Answer (score 14):

The general pattern you're looking for is:

```
@*[contains(., 'string')]
```

which will match any attribute on the context element that contains `string`.  So if you simply want to search the whole document for attributes containing `string`, you'd use:

```
//@*[contains(., 'string')]
```

Comment: Short and sweet

Answer (score -1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
//*[@*[starts-with(., 'h')]]
```