# XPath query for matching any attribute with name starting with X

Tags: xpath

From this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7405471/431780), I can see how to match on **any** attribute values that start with a particular string. For example, finding a list of elements that have *any* attribute with a value starting with the letter h:

`//*[@*[starts-with(., 'h')]]`

My question is how to match attribute *names* that start with a particular string?

As I understand it, the `@*` indicates matching any attribute within the wider `//*` collection of any elements. The `starts-with` function takes two parameters, the haystack and the needle, and the `.` haystack indicates the attribute value. I feel like I'm 90% of my way there, but I can't figure out what I need to match on the **attribute name, rather than value**.

Example matches:

```
<example>
    <first match-me="123">MATCH!</first>
    <second do-not-match-me="456">NO MATCH!</second>
    <third match-me-yes-please="789">MATCH!</third>
    <fourth>
        <fifth match-me:oh-yes>MATCH!</fifth>
    </fourth>
</example>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I feel like I'm 90% of my way there" - yes, the last phase is specifying attribute name method:

```
//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'match-me')]]
```

Note, relying on simple attribute name matching you may encounter an issue when dealing with attribute names like `match-me:oh-yes` (colon inside). In such cases, you'll probably get an error `The prefix "match-me" for attribute "match-me:oh-yes" associated with an element type "fifth" is not bound` OR `Attribute name "match-me:oh-yes" associated with an element type "fifth" must be followed by the ' = ' character.`(in case of "valueless" attribute)